# Electron - Main process not wating for the showOpendialog to return file content

Tags: javascript, async-await, electron

I have the following communication going on

```
//main process
ipcMain.on('asynchronous-message', (event, arg) => {
    getFile()
    mainWindow.webContents.send('asynchronous-message',contents)
    mainWindow.openDevTools();
})
async function getFile(){
  const {filePaths} = await dialog.showOpenDialog({properties:['openFile']});
  contents =  fs.readFileSync(filePaths[0],'utf-8')

}
```

```
//renderer process
function openFS(){
    ipc.send('asynchronous-message', 'ping')
    ipc.on('asynchronous-message',(event,arg)=>{
        console.log(arg)
    })
}
```

in the main process i have the `getFile` function that is fetching a files content
but the `ipc.Main` doesn't wait for it it immediately returns undefined to the renderer process and thats what it prints on the `dev tools`

I know this for certain because if i remove the show open dialog and hard code the path to the file i wanna fetch , it successfully prints the content of the file in the `dev tools` because it doesnt need to spend the time on the file system

Comment: Are you 100% sure that `getFile` always returns a string? Maybe wrap the `webContents.send` in a try catch and log `typeof fileContents` on error.

Comment: i have done some edits @szydlovski

Comment: The `getFile` function is async, and the `asynchronous-message` handler is sync. It fires the `getFile` function and continues execution, sending the current value of `contents` (undefined because at this point `getFile` has not yet changed it). You need to make the handler async, and await `getFile`. Also, using globals like this is generally a bad idea, you can handle the dialog and reading the file within the handler.

Comment: @szydlovski okay , that makes sense tbh , now.....how do i make the handler async , i thought it is xactly what it says :) , and yah , i had to use globas because the mainWindow is not in the same scope , it is totally out of reach

Comment: Like with any other function: `ipcMain.on('asynchronous-message', async (event, arg) => { ... }`. While the communication is always async, the handler itself can be synchronous. You can then simply move the `dialog` and `fs` operations inside the handler.

Comment: @szydlovski that works like a charm , and now im very angry because i knew how is that done but my mind.......just didnt ping me.....yah...write that as an answer

Comment: If you’re satisfied that @szydlovski’s solution does the job, you should accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your message handler is synchronous, therefore the `getFile` call is fired but the handler does not wait until it finishes execution, and sends the current value of `contents` (undefined because at this point `getFile` has not yet changed it).

You need to make the handler async and await the `getFile` call.

```js
ipcMain.on('asynchronous-message', async (event, arg) => {
    await getFile()
    mainWindow.webContents.send('asynchronous-message',contents)
    mainWindow.openDevTools();
})
```

Or better yet, get rid of the global variable by handling what `getFile` does directly in the handler (it's also better to use non-blocking `fs` functions):

```js
ipcMain.on('asynchronous-message', async (event, arg) => {
    const {filePaths} = await dialog.showOpenDialog({properties:['openFile']});
    const contents = await fs.promises.readFile(filePaths[0], 'utf-8');
    mainWindow.webContents.send('asynchronous-message', contents);
    mainWindow.openDevTools();
})
```